# Por que isso está retornando None?

Tags: python, regex

Estou tendo dificuldades com os ajustes de certas palavras geradas aleatoriamente, mais especificamente, problemas na hora de consestar certas palavras como `ziiːno`, onde não quero duas letras iguais se encontrem, mas esse é o resultado:

```
import re

test_word = "ziiːno"
print(re.match(r"(.)\1ː?", test_word))
# None
```

Isto deveria retornar `iiː` ou `i` pelo que fiz no regex101. Alguem sabe o que está acontecendo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match):

> *re.match() checks for a match only at the beginning of the string, while re.search() checks for a match anywhere in the string*

Ou seja, `match` faz a busca a partir do início da string. Se quer buscar em qualquer parte da string, use `search`.

Outro detalhe é que estas funções retornam um objeto `Match`. Se você quer **apenas o texto** que a regex pegou, pode pegar o grupo zero do `Match` (usando `[0]`), [que corresponde a todo o trecho capturado](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.__getitem__):

```py
import re

test_word = "ziiːno"
print(re.search(r"(.)\1ː?", test_word)[0]) # ii:
```

Comment: eu jurava que essas duas funcionavam da mesma forma, valeu pela ajuda e por me lembrar de sempre olhar a documentação.